# what is the virtue of lightroom's print module?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, printing

i know that the print module is used to develop a photo for printing; my question is what advantage you to obtain in developing>print module>export as jpeg, as compared to devlop>export as tiff file?

the print module wont let you save as a tiff file.  why is this?

what features are useful in the print module that are not available in the develop module?

Comment: Please use standard capitalization in your Stack Exchange posts. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking more then one thing here.

1. Why doesn't the Print module have an option to save as TIFF
2. Why does the print module exist
3. What advantages does TIFF have over JPEG

Answers below:

1. It is anybody's guess who isn't on the development team, but it has been requested as a feature to add in the future([here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeedback.photoshop.com%2Fphotoshop_family%2Ftopics%2Flightroom4_beta_print_module_outputs&ei=VYj0VJ2kBcyryATE9IGoDg&usg=AFQjCNG3uOzHPZzgKsLPIqaTIFGVamxDSA&sig2=dZ5ieFaa5BsyEIx7_AuaIg&bvm=bv.87269000,d.aWw) and [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/958022?start=0&tstart=0)).
2. Its main advantages are to setup contact sheets and customized layouts via templates
3. See existing answers here: [Should I use JPG or TIFF for high-quality prints?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10895/should-i-use-jpg-or-tiff-for-high-quality-prints)

Comment: the customized layouts made from templates; these can be produced in photoshop aswell simply from cropping no? so is the benefit of doing this in lightroom just that you can do this in batches instead of individually?

Comment: You can do basically everything that Photoshop can do in *Photoshop* Lightroom. But yes, you can do it in batches or in higher volumes with much more ease and speed.